# How to set to user selection after AJAX reload?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

`#whs_id` is a drop down field on `partial form_list` of a Rails 4.2 page.

```
<%= select_tag(:whs_id, options_for_select(return_misc_definitions('warehouse').map{|r| [r.name, r.id]}), include_blank: true) %></p>
```

Here is the `.change` event for the `#whs_id`:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#whs_id', function (){  //only document/'body' works with every change. ('#whs_id') only works once.
    $.get(window.location, {whs_id: $('#whs_id').val()}, null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Here is the `js` code to handle the `change` event and reload the `partial` `form_list` and set `#whs_id` to user's selection:

```
  <% @items = @items.where(whs_id: params[:whs_id].to_i)  %>
  $('#index_page').html("<%= escape_javascript render partial: 'form_list', locals: {models: @items, whs_id: params[:whs_id]} %>");
  $('#whs_id').val("<%=params[:whs_id]%>");  //set to user selection.
```

The problem is that after `ajax` reload, the `#whs_id` is always `blank` no matter what a user selects. The line of `$('#whs_id').val` does not set to the user's selection. What's is the right way to set to user's selection after `ajax` reload?

Comment: hi, have you been able to open the javascript console and check that there are no javascript errors? Have you verified that `params[:whs_id]` is not nil at this point too?

Comment: The code above actually works. I guess that I must use the name instead of the `params[:whs_id]` inside the `val` in previous test.